# classy sassy and a bit smart assy

Tags: slang, idiom-meaning

> classy sassy and a bit smart assy

Can someone please explain the meaning of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"classy" = stylish
"sassy" = spirited, cheeky
'smart assy" = an adjective, facetiously derived from "smart ass," slang for someone who's an irritating know-it-all